# How to show the "description" of a Hyperlink column in the Datasheet View?

Tags: datasheet

I have a list that uses a Hyperlink column (which contains the URL and description). When I use Datasheet View, I do not have the option to input the description field. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the field in datasheet view, there should be a context menu that contains Hyperlink > Edit Hyperlink...

This menu item will pop up a dialog window where you can enter both the url and description.