# Open with Access grayed out

Tags: list, microsoft-access

I cannot use the functionality "Open with Access" on a SP list. I recently installed SharePoint Designer and that seemed to cause the problem. I navigate to the list and can see the "Open with Access" button but it is grayed out.

Comment: What is sharepoint Version, Which browser you are using? 32bit or 64bit?what is the office version?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on premises, Internet Explorer 32bit, Office 2016 32bit. Sorry for not elaborating in the 1st post.

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e37f162a-ed64-460a-b109-0b001e4de2c2/open-with-access-disabled-in-sharepoint-2010-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious  what i am thinking may be it is becuase of office 2016 compatibility issue with sharepoint 2013

Comment: I think it's an ActiveX thing. I checked the User's Internet Explorer Add-ons and she's missing Database Launcher addon

Answer (score 1):

This was caused in our environment by conflicting Office versions. Designer is only available as a 2013 application. If you install this alongside Office 2016/365, SharePoint will look for Access 2013 instead of Access 2016. Not finding it, that button gets grayed out. You may also receive an error message when exporting Lists to Excel indicating that there is no "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application," even though the export ultimately works.

You can fix both issues by removing Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support from Designer and any other Office applications that are not part of your 2016 suite. If you have more than one non-2016 Office application (like maybe InfoPath), you have to do this for all of them.

1. Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features
2. Select the non-2016 Office application (Designer in your case)
3. Click the Change button
4. Select Add or Remove Features > Continue
5. Expand Office Tools Select (do not Expand) "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support"
6. Right click > Select "Not Available" Click Continue and complete that
   process.
7. Return to Programs and Features
8. Repeat for any other non-2016 Office applications
9. Return to Programs and Features
10. Select your current Office suite (2016 or 365)
11. Click Change
12. Select Quick Repair
13. When that is done, reboot

When you next visit the site, your Access button should be available again.

Removing the feature looks like this:[image: Removing MS SP Foundation Support]

This solution adapted from the findings here: https://breezesupport.qorusdocs.com/hc/en-us/articles/206887635-Microsoft-SharePoint-Foundation-Error-Multiple-Office-Product-Versions-

Comment: I actually have the same problem. Try's the above solution, but it did not do the trick. I have SPO 365, Office 365 & Designer 2013. The "Open in Access" button is still grey'd out.

Comment: This solution is verified to work when the condition appears in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise On Prem. SPO 365 may have a different conflict.