# Sharepoint 2013, Office 2016, Infopath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, office-2016

With the combination of SharePoint 2013, Office 2016, and InfoPath 2013 installed we are experiencing issues using "Export to Excel" and "Open with Access" when viewing lists.

Exporting to Excel works, but not without first bringing up a message of "To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application."

The "Open with Access" button remains greyed out and unclickable.

Uninstalling InfoPath 2013 fixes these issues and removes the warning, but we are using quite a bit of InfoPath forms currently.

This is using Windows 7 and IE 11.

Are there any patches either for Office, IE, or SharePoint that address this issue? I can find some similar situations in other questions, but most of the time the solution was to just only have Office 2016 installed, but we still need InfoPath at this point. We are looking to different forms solutions for the future but not at the stage to replace it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by disabling Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support in the Office 2013 applications via Control Panel > Programs and Features > Office 2013 application > Change > Add/Remove features.

I've posted detailed steps in a similar thread here: [Open with Access grayed out](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190759/open-with-access-grayed-out/215028#215028)

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the InfoPath and Office are different versions.

If you want to have the InfoPath which is compatible with the Office 2016, you could download the “InfoPath 2013 for Office 365 ProPlus Subscription” product.

Here is the download link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48734

Information about InfoPath and Office 2016:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_infopath_bloggers/2016/03/01/infopath-is-not-included-in-office-2016/

In addition, it is recommend using Office 2013 with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: That is the version of InfoPath I have installed and the program itself works fine. I'm looking more to see if there is a solution to have that functionality in SharePoint work without going back to Office 2013 for the rest of the Office Suite. My Company is pushing out Office 2016 relatively soon